# How to add mutlipel subtitles using protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg?

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

Currently I using this [package](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg) to intract with ffmpeg. And I can encode 1 single subtitle file using this code:

```php
$format = new X264();

FFMpeg::openUrl($videoUrl)
    ->addFilter(function (VideoFilters $filters) use ($tmpSubtitleFilePath) {
            $filters->custom("subtitles={$subtitleFilePath}");
    })
    ->export()
    ->inFormat($format)
    ->save($tmpVideoPath);
```

lets say I have translation file and a transcript file. **I want to encode the video for both of them** so the user can swaitch between them as he likes.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add multiple subtitles using the addSubtitles method provided by the `protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg` package. This method accepts an array of subtitle files, where each entry in the array is an instance of the `FFMpeg\Coordinate\Subtitle` class.`

    use FFMpeg\Coordinate\Subtitle;
    use Protonemedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg;
    
   $format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();

    //change this will your path
    $saveVideoPath = 'path/to/output.mp4';
    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create();
    
    $video = $ffmpeg->open($videoUrl);
    
    $subtitles = [
        new Subtitle('path/to/subtitle1.srt'),
        new Subtitle('path/to/subtitle2.srt'),
        new Subtitle('path/to/subtitle3.srt')
    ];
    
    $video->addSubtitles($subtitles);
    
    $video->save($format, $saveVideoPath);

//May be it will help you...
```

Comment: addSubtitles function doesnt exist

Comment: Can you try `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle1.srt -i subtitle2.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -c copy -c:s srt output.mkv`

Comment: where  video "video.mp4", the subtitles "subtitle1.srt" and "subtitle2.srt" and then it will merge them and save the output to "output.mkv"

Comment: but how can I use the command with the pacakge. It will give errors.